# How do I bring an unused engagement ring into Canada for a vacation?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, us-citizens

I'm going to Canada on vacation with my significant other. I have an engagement ring and want to propose while there. We are both US citizens and I bought the ring in the US.

I'm concerned that I won't be able to bring the ring through customs at the border without alerting my significant other.

I have two questions:

**1. Do I need to declare the ring?**

I read the [E311 declaration form page](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/forms-formulaires/e311-eng.html), and two places sound like the answer is "yes", but I'd like to make sure:

- *Duty-free allowance only applies to gifts (excludes alcohol and tobacco) valued at no more than CAN$60 each.*

  Does the ring qualify as a gift, even though it's for someone traveling with me?
- *Each traveller is responsible for reporting currency and/or monetary instruments totaling CAN$10,000 or more that are in his or her actual possession or baggage.*

  Does the ring count as a "monetary instrument"? Its appraised value is over $10,000 CAN.

**2. If I do declare the ring, will it obviously alert my significant other?** In other words, would I likely need to discuss the ring with a customs officer, show appraisal paperwork, etc. in front of my significant other?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This question was previously asked and answered at  *[How do I get an engagement ring past security/customs in an airport without alerting my significant other?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37054)*

Comment: To clarify something omitted in the other answer, assuming that the ring will eventually leave Canada with your fiance (or you will be taking it home with you if things don't go as planned) then you should not need to declare it. Duty is only for things staying in the country.