# Am I allowed to take an "All in One Water cooler" in my carry-on luggage?

Tags: usa, airport-security, electronic-items, tsa, swiss-citizens

This is a follow up question of [Am I allowed to take a GPU in my carry-on luggage?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49350/am-i-allowed-to-take-a-gpu-in-my-carry-on-luggage)

During my stay in LA I will be checking if some graphics cards are cheaper in the US and if yes I would like to buy 2 of them and import into switzerland. I already know that I would have to pay 8% VAT when I am importing them into Switzerland.

Now that the new AMD graphics card series has been released, I am especially looking at the Fury X which has an all in one water cooler. Does anyone know how the regulations are for water coolers as they logically have water in them? Am I allowed to take them in my carry-on luggage?

The main point of concern for me is that the water cooler have liquid in them, which is only allowed to a limited degree at security checks. Or I would be better off packing it into my suitcase?

Comment: Pack it in your suitcase. The simplistic reasoning is that it contains liquid hence will be treated as such. Dies it contain more than 100ml of liquid? If so you'll have to throw it away. Are you prepared to risk it?

Comment: I doubt that it contains more than 100ml, However how would they measure how much water is in inside the watercooler. And how would they then decide when to throw it away when they can't measure the amount of water?

Comment: If you're lucky they read the specs, or try to look for capacity written on the device (like they do with cosmetics and such). If you're unlucky they just throw it away. Remember that TSA always wins.

Comment: People keep saying the TSA will just dispose of anything that doesn't pass their checks. Can't you simply decline to pass security at this point in time, and go back and either A) Check it in at the desk or B)give it to someone who isn't flying? I know people who have done this before with expensive drinks (although possibly not in the USA)

Comment: @CMaster You probably can decline to pass security and go back to check your luggage in the cargo hold. The question is: do you have the time to do so? What if the luggage drop-off deadline has already passed?

Comment: Unfortunately, the rule is *not* that it must contain less than 100 ml of liquid. The container itself must be smaller than 100 ml *and* fit in a 1L plastic bag. Almost empty 1.5L bottles get thrown away everyday.

Comment: @Relaxed The airports I've been to seem to allow empty water bottles just fine, though. So just dump the rest out of your 1.5L bottle and refill it within the secure area. Which would imply that, if it is possible to drain the water (or whatever liquid it is) out of the graphics card and then refill it later, that would be the route to go if carry-on baggage is a must.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're proposing to bring this device through a security checkpoint:

[image: Fury X]

The more interesting question is, will they even realize that it contains liquid?

Seems doubtful to me, simply because it doesn't look anything like a water bottle. Chances are it'll go right through without comment.

But based solely on the device's construction I would not *want* to take it in hand luggage unboxed, before arriving at your destination, because of the risk of it being damaged.

And if you're going to declare it and pay import duties on it anyway, then you may as well leave it in its sealed packaging until you get home. Which means it'll travel a bit large for hand luggage and you're better off sticking it in your suitcase. Besides, what are you going to do with it on the plane?

Comment: "Besides, what are you going to do with it on the plane?" Carress it gently?

Comment: One reason to take it as carry-on would be concern about theft/loss/damage to hold luggage.

Comment: Yes the reason why I would want to carry it in the carry-on luggage would be to prevent damage to it which may happen when my suitcase gets moved around in the airport. Also I don't see why this could break when I carry them by myself? The only thing that could break would be the water tubes / seals. However when you dont bend them too much it should be fine

Comment: @RononDex It's a lot safer in its original box than unpacked! After all, it's _designed_ to ship as (air) cargo in that box.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Good point. Didn't think of that. Will have to check how swiss (my airline) handels several luggage parts.

Comment: Anecdotally, liquids show up pretty good on an X-ray machine. I once tried to bring a squirt gun full of water. It did not go unnoticed.

Comment: "what are you doing with it on the plane" - it's not what happens on the plane, it's the 10m high volleyball court called "baggage handling" where they rip it to pieces, shoot at it and who knows what else. I wouldn't want to check anything remotely fragile.

Comment: @niico In its original package it's safe as houses, unless they use it as a football at the World Cup. Then it might have a problem. After all it was designed to ship as cargo in that package.

Comment: Agreed. I was thinking more like - you have a build now how do you take that build on a plane...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the permitted degree of the liquid. but if the cooled material used(even its quantity may be less but the chemical used to give cooling air, is got noted during the scan)  in the Fury X is got more possibility of being checked by the security and even you are ready to pay the 8% VAT.it can happen if they allowed you keep, else you need to leave it and move,as money spent is be got wasted.