# To have GPU (computer's graphic card) in hand luggage?

Tags: hand-luggage

I need new GPU for my computer and must buy it from Finland. I am travelling with AirBaltics from Finland. 
I would like to take the following GPU in my hand luggage because they break easily:

[image]

Can you get get GPU in hand luggage?

Comment: Yes, but you should leave it in its box! It will ship perfectly well in checked baggage. See also [this question about a water cooled GPU in hand luggage](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/49480/3221).

Comment: @MichaelHampton My GPU does not contain liquid.

Comment: Your GPU is also much safer in its original package.

Comment: Yes, but I want to save money. Is it allowed in hand luggage?

Comment: Yes, it's allowed.