# Travelling to Russia with engagement ring?

Tags: russia

I have already read these two questions: [If I don't declare a not-yet-used engagement ring at airport security, am I smuggling jewelry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/if-i-dont-declare-a-not-yet-used-engagement-ring-at-airport-security-am-i-smug) and [How do I get an engagement ring past security/customs in an airport without alerting my significant other?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37054/how-do-i-get-an-engagement-ring-past-security-customs-in-an-airport-without-aler), and I saw some valuable advices, but now I want to ask specifically for Russia.

My friends and I are going to Russia, and my friend would like to propose his girlfriend there. What would be procedure so that his girlfriend doesn't find out of course. I have read somewhere that a person can import goods in a value of 1500 US$ and not to declare it, above that you have to declare goods. Ring is of value around 700 US$.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By air transport: up to 10000€ and not heavier than 50 kg. I think the engagement ring would pass these criteria.

> **The goods for private use except transport vehicles imported on
> customs territory of customs union  in accompanied or unaccompanied
> luggage**
>
> 1. Goods for private use  (except ethanol and the indivisible goods) transported by air transport:
>
> customs cost of which does not exceed the sum equivalent of 10 000 euros and gross weight of which does not
> exceed 50 kgs

Source: [Federal Customs Service of Russia](http://eng.customs.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=72:ab-the-ord&catid=37:moving-of-the-goods-by-physical-persons-for-a-private-use-through-customs-border-of-the-customs-union-and-fulfillment-of-the-customs-operations-connected-with-their-release&Itemid=1849&Itemid=1910).