# Buying tech merchandising in New York

Tags: usa, new-york-city, shopping

I've been browsing some websites like

- [Microsoft merchandising](http://shop.ecompanystore.com/mscompanystore/home)
- [Google Merchandise Shop](https://www.googlemerchandisestore.com)

and I want to buy some stuff. I live in Argentina, so I don't want to buy online because (a) the shipping costs are way too high, and (b) I might not even get it (yeah, the postal service in my country is so bad).

Is there any physical place in New York where I can get this kind of stuff? And if there isn't, can I buy it online and put the hotel address?

Comment: Are you currently in NY or are you planning to travel there, and want to purchase the items and then collect them at the hotel when you arrive?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i'm planning to go there around August

Comment: @choster he's not after electronics, he's after Microsoft and Google merchandising (eg tshirts with their logos on).  Potentially still too broad, just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy it online, and have it sent to your hotel. Contact the hotel ahead of time, to let them know to expect the package(s).  Some hotels will charge a nominal handling fee for packages. Most, in my experience, don't.

Online orders in the US for commodity items are almost always cheaper online than in brick-and-mortar stores for obvious reasons: Less overhead.

When I'm in the US I almost always "stock up" on things... I have electronics, clothing items (those of which I'm certain of the correct size), or recently an [engagement ring](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/37045/444), all mailed to my hotel.

Comment: Congratulations :)